# Python CSV Output Blank Cells

Tags: python, csv, nltk

I am trying to write the exact shell output of my python code into a csv file (including the blank fields). My Python output looks like this. I have tried to get my head around but for some reason, I am getting output that looks like this.

```
contractNN
develop NN
manag   NN
order   NN
parti   NN
suitabl NN
supplier NN
work    NN
```

CSV Output Desired

```
[[(u'contract', 'NN'), (u'develop', 'NN'), (u'manag', 'NN'), (u'order', 'NN'), (u'parti', 'NN'), (u'suitabl', 'NN'), (u'supplier', 'NN'), (u'work', 'NN')]]
[[(u'microsoft', 'NN')]]
[[(u'hadoop', 'NN')]]
[[]]
[[(u'python', 'NN'), (u'python', 'NN')]]
[[]]
[[]]
```

My Python Code

```
import csv
import nltk
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk import stem
import numpy as np

output_file = open('examp_output.csv', 'w')
datawriter = csv.writer(output_file)

"""Bunch of NLTK Code"""

    print [m]

    datawriter.writerows(m)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: I wonder how the output is going to contain entries like `Microsoft` that don't exist in the input

Comment: The desired output doesn't look like CSV. See examples here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - I know :) !! this is just an example for your review.

Comment: @mastazi - Basically, I wanted to save the python output words into a csv format. For e.g. [[(u'contract', 'NN'), (u'develop', 'NN'), (u'manag', 'NN'), (u'order', 'NN'), (u'parti', 'NN'), (u'suitabl', 'NN'), should be saved as contract develop manag order etc...

Comment: @simon_xia - I tried  the link you shared but some reason, I am not able to get the desired output. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead of using CSVWriter

```
import os
output_file = open('example.txt','w') #use 'a' instead of 'w' to append  instead of overwrite the text file if you're doing this in a loop
output_file.write(data_out)
os.rename('example.txt', 'example.csv')
```

Comment: It looks like you're just writing the whole list of tuples to your csv file. Since a csv file is nothing more than a specially formatted text file with a different extension you can write to a text file then rename it at the end.